# ¿Cómo sé en PHP si un mssql_query que hace un update arroja un affect_rows como en mysql?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Si escribo esto en PHP, ¿cómo sé si me hace un cambio en SQL Server 2008 r2?

```
$rows = mssql_query('UPDATE database.dbo.persona set contenido = contenido');
if (mssql_num_rows_Affect ($rows)==0)
    die ('No se realizo ningun cambio');
```

En MySQL lanzaría un `affect_rows`, pero ¿cómo lo puedo comprobar con `mssql_query`?

Comment: A modo de consejo, ya que estas aprendiendo, te sugeriria que usaras [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) para sql server. Si te fijas las funciones mssql_* estas depreciadas y fueron removidas en PHP 7.0

Answer (score 2):

Sería algo tal que así:

```
  $con = mssql_connect('Tus parámetros de conexión');
  mssql_select_db('tuBD', $con);

  $sql = 'UPDATE database.dbo.persona set contenido = contenido';
  $res = mssql_query($sql,$con);

  if (!$res) {
    print("Consulta fallida");
  } else {
    $number_of_rows = mssql_rows_affected($con);
    print("$number_of_rows filas afectadas.\n");
  }

  mssql_close($con);
```

De todas formas te recomiendo no utilizar `mssql` porque en `php7` está obsoleto y es muy vulnerable a inyecciones sql, ya que no permite realizar sentencias preparadas. Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por aquí: [PDO odbc](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-odbc.php)